# i915 error after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: boot

I am new to Ubuntu, so not sure of anything yet.

But after upgrading to 15.10 I get this error 'intel pipe config compare i915 error mismatch in ips_enabled' after I the grub screen when I load Ubuntu.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Is that message the only problem?

Comment: Maybe bug 1492764.

Comment: well so far that is what I picked up and now I dont even get to the login screen

Comment: I have the same problem. Really annoyed and quite unhappy with myself for upgrading.

Comment: I was so excited for 15.10 since I am new to ubuntu. Still am though and really don't want to go back to windows.

Comment: i'm going to resintall 15.04 or even stay with LTS 14.04 which is very stable.

Comment: I solved this by reinstalling 15.10 from a USB stick (previous install was upgrade from 15.04). It kept my home dir and some apps.  I gave a more detailed answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/691406/laptop-wont-boot-after-upgrade-to-15-10-the-master-control-interrupt-lied-any/692531#692531

Comment: I solved this issue for now, by switching from gdm to lightgdm, I hope that, that was the problem as i have been doing alot of updating and stuff by various commands via tty.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. There are a couple of bug threads related to the errors I'm seeing and they claim to have fixed it in the nightly kernels.

[dmesg shows "drm:gen8_irq_handler i915 *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1488719)

[Intel Display i915 driver crashes, Asus Zenbook 303LA](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1492632)

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this issue (at least for me) was to remove the usage of `nomodeset` from `/etc/default/grub` (requires to manually execute `sudo update-grub` afterwards to actually apply the change). Rebooting the Intel i915 driver load normally.