# Laptop won't boot after upgrade to 15.10: The master control interrupt lied (any kernel)

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, lenovo, 15.10

I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 on a Lenovo Carbon X1 (3rd gen), and now when the laptop boots it stops with the message:

```
[drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
```

I tried different kernels (4.x upstart, recovery, 3.19) and they all throw the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your laptop connected to an external monitor? I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1488719) bug that seems relevant.

Comment: No, its not connected to anything. I've seen the refs to external monitors mentioned. Its a new laptop, worked great at 15.04. Dead with 15.10.

Comment: You could try booting with the `nomodeset` boot parameter.

Comment: I will try yes though I don't get a black screen or anything like that - just a the boot process logs which then gets stuck with that error. I am thinking to reinstall 14.04 (or maybe 15.04) which were fine and stable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would apply to everyone, but it worked for me: I downloaded 15.10 to a USB stick and run the installation again from scratch. 
It wrote over the existing install, kept my home directory and even some of the installed applications. For example, once I reinstalled Java from Oracle, the previously installed PyCharm started working again. Even steam still had my account logged in once I reinstalled it.

Comment: And then it didn't work.... Worked for a while, then reverted back to the same error message on boot.